# função retorna undefined array de strings

Tags: javascript

Tenho tentado exibir os saldos dos usuarios no seguinte cenário, porém me deparo sempre com esses erros:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lenght' of undefined
    at somaNumeros (C:\Users\leona\rockseat\ex05.js:26:24)
    at calculaSaldo (C:\Users\leona\rockseat\ex05.js:35:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leona\rockseat\ex05.js:45:24)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47?[39m
```

Peço a ajuda dos amigos, muito obrigado

```
const usuarios = [
    {
        nome: 'Salvio',
        receitas: [115.3, 48.7, 98.3, 14.5],
        despesas:[85.3, 13.5, 19.9]
    },
    {
        nome: 'Marcio',
        receitas: [24.6, 214.3, 45.3],
        despesas: [185.3, 21.1, 120.0]
    },
    {
        nome: 'Lucia',
        receitas: [9.8, 120.3, 340.2, 45.3],
        despesas: [450.2, 29.9]
    }


]



function somaNumeros(numeros)
{
    var soma = 0
    for(i=0; i< numeros.length; i++) 
    {
        soma = soma + numeros[i]
    }

    return soma
}
function calculaSaldo(receitas , despesas)
{
    const totalDespesas = somaNumeros(receitas)
    const totalReceitas = somaNumeros(despesas)
    return totalReceitas - totalDespesas
}




for(i=0;i<usuarios.length;i++)
{
    var saldototal = calculaSaldo(usuarios.receitas,usuarios.despesas)
    if(saldototal>0){
        console.log(`${usuarios.nome} possui saldo POSITIVO de ${saldototal}`)
    }else{
        console.log(`${usuarios.nome} possui saldo negativo de ${saldototal}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: ash, o código que você postou deve estar diferente do que gerou o erro, mas perceba o seguinte, o erro diz que ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'lenght'```, essa propriedade na verdade é ```length```, você inverteu o "th" no final.

Comment: JavaScript não é Java, por favor, retire a tag `Java`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o erro é simples,

mas, primeiro, vou tentar mostrar como se faz o debug do codigo, especialmente em javascript, pois basta correr o código no browser:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/plpivwi52xdirhp/yo9AqxWq6h.mp4

acabou por ser simples, pois o seu loop `for` chama o array, quando deveria chamar apenas um object no array:

```js
for (i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i += 1)
{
   var usuario = usuarios[i];
   var saldototal = calculaSaldo(usuario.receitas, usuario.despesas);

   ...
}
```

---

**Adicionado** pelo comentário

o erro de apenas mostrar um, tem haver com ["variable scoping"](https://www.google.com/search?q=variable+scoping+in+javascript) e é de simples resolucao...

existem 2 loops `for`, com a mesma variavel, pelo que ao adicionar 1 ao `i` de um for, esse fica vai existir como variavle global, e ao sendo chamado `somaNumeros()`, apesar de o setar com `0`, esse `i` vai novamente ser somado, ao foltar ao loop `for` original, na segunda interaccao, sairá do loop pois a condicao `i < usuarios.length` já foi alcancada.

ou seja, por outras palavras, caso o texto acima esteja confuso: a variavle `i` usada nos dois loops `for` como nõ sao initializadas com `var` ou `let`, fica automaticamente como variavel global.

adicione `var` à variavel `i`, para que fique: `for ( var i = 0; ...` e vai ver que todos os valores serão mostrados.

o seu código, deveria ser:

```js
var usuarios = [{
    nome: 'Salvio',
    receitas: [115.3, 48.7, 98.3, 14.5],
    despesas: [85.3, 13.5, 19.9]
  },
  {
    nome: 'Marcio',
    receitas: [24.6, 214.3, 45.3],
    despesas: [185.3, 21.1, 120.0]
  },
  {
    nome: 'Lucia',
    receitas: [9.8, 120.3, 340.2, 45.3],
    despesas: [450.2, 29.9]
  }
];

function somaNumeros(numeros) {
  var soma = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i += 1) soma += numeros[i];
  return soma;
}

function calculaSaldo(receitas, despesas) {
  const totalDespesas = somaNumeros(receitas);
  const totalReceitas = somaNumeros(despesas);
  return totalReceitas - totalDespesas;
}

(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i += 1) {
    var usuario = usuarios[i];
    var saldototal = calculaSaldo(usuario.receitas, usuario.despesas);

    var tipoSaldo = saldototal > 0 ? 'POSITIVO' : 'negativo';
    console.log(
      `${usuario.nome} possui saldo ${tipoSaldo} de ${saldototal.toFixed(2)}`);
  }
})(); // funcão que corre automáticamente
```

Comment: muito obrigado amigo

Comment: eu percebi que só imprime o primeiro usuario apos realizar essa mudança, como sera que posso imprimir todos ?

Comment: adicionei na resposta... se a resposta ajudar, lembre-se de marcar como certa 

Comment: feito amigo, muito agradecido irmão